# AutoCompleteBox in silverlight toolkit for windows phone wrong display

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm having a problem with the autocompletebox from the toolkit for windows phone. I bind it to some data, then when i press it and start typing, it discovers some items but they are displayed wrong (the list is shown separated from the box, and also if i click on any item, nothing happens. If i click where the item would be supposed to be (for example, right on the top of the box), then it gets selected. It looks like a rendering problem (bug?)) but perhaps i'm doing something wrong. Here's the code for the box :

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate1">
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding Name}" Margin="8,7"/>
        </DataTemplate>

<toolkit:AutoCompleteBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" x:Name="txtSelectValues" MinWidth="250" Margin="0,0,0,0" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DataTemplate1}" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it. It's a bug with the AutoCompleteBox. When inside a scrollviewer control, the dropdown gets messed up and displayed in an incorrect position

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Its not just that is also to do with being placed inside of a Pivot/Panaroma as well as the scrollviewer,  the silverlight gurus have stated they haven't a timeline for the fix for the Pivot control, and there is a nasty hack

http://silverlight.codeplex.com/workitem/7574

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer might just be that you shouldn't be using a `ContentControl` directly used like this. Try using something like a `TextBlock` instead - e.g.:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate1">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="8,7"/>
    </DataTemplate>
```

---

If that's not the answer, then try pulling back to a simple example - especially removing all the Margin's, Width's, Alignment's, etc - then put them back in one-by-one to work out and understand what is causing the effect you are seeing.

Comment: well, i did as you suggested and removed all the margin, minwidth, etc from both the datatemplate and the autocompletebox, but it still shows in the top. I think that something else is probably interfering, but I guess it must be a bug, because another control shouldn't affect how this one looks right?

Comment: Ok, i think I found the problem. I had a scrollviewer, after removing it, the control started showing correctly. Definitely that's a bug in the control, i'll report it to microsoft