# AutoCompleteBox wrong item selected on SelectedItem (probably xaml issue)

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit

I've been fighting for a while with an autocompletebox in silverlight for windows phone (toolkit) and can't seem to figure out what's happening

I've got a simple search box, binded to a list of custom items. When the selectionchanged event fires, there's somewhere a problem and the item that i click is not the one that comes as SelectedItem. I realized that when i select, let's say the first item, nothing happens. When i select the 2nd item, the 1st one gets actually selected, and so on. It's like if the items were phased out by 1

Here's the important piece code

control :

```
<toolkit:AutoCompleteBox MinimumPrefixLength="0" Text="{Binding Localizedresources.Search, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" MinWidth="270" ItemsSource="{Binding AutoCompleteEntities}" x:Name="txtSelectEntity" ValueMemberBinding="{Binding }" ItemTemplate="{Binding AutoCompleteTemplate}" IsDropDownOpen="True" MaxDropDownHeight="200" >
                    </toolkit:AutoCompleteBox>
```

template (added a blue border because i thought first that i wasn't touching the right part)

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="AutoCompleteTemplate">
            <Border BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="2">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding GermanMeaning}"></TextBlock>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

damn this control
ok, it looks like it's related to the same bug that makes [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7351898/autocompletebox-in-silverlight-toolkit-for-windows-phone-wrong-display) happen

I had created a transition :

```
<toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition>
        <toolkit:NavigationInTransition>
            <toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Backward>
                <toolkit:TurnstileTransition
            Mode="BackwardIn" />
            </toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Backward>
            <toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>
                <toolkit:TurnstileTransition
            Mode="ForwardIn" />
            </toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>
        </toolkit:NavigationInTransition>
    </toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition>
    <toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationOutTransition>
        <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition>
            <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Backward>
                <toolkit:TurnstileTransition
            Mode="BackwardOut" />
            </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Backward>
            <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Forward>
                <toolkit:TurnstileTransition
            Mode="ForwardOut" />
            </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Forward>
        </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition>
    </toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationOutTransition>
```

to make the page switching look cooler, but it appears that those lines of code that have absolutetly nothing to do with the autocompletebox, mess it up. I hope somebody fixes these horrible random bugs at some point, not only they're nasty but they're also super difficult to catch (this made me lose like 3hs)